# Very basic example doesnt work

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Can someone explain me why this simple example doesn't work?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.11/angular.min.js"></script>


<p>{{accountID}}</p>

<input class="form-control input-sm" uib-tooltip="Search by Account ID" validator="/^[0-9]{1,15}$/" validator-invoke="watch" validator-error="Account ID must have 1 to 15 digits." type="number" placeholder="Search by Account ID"
  ng-model="accountID" min="1" required>
```

Comment: you are missing `ng-app`. Simple wrap your code with `<div ng-app> ... </div>`. Additionally, the input field uses `ui.bootstrap` module, that you would need to inject into `angular.module`

Answer (score 2):

You need to include wrap your code between `<div ng-app>...</div>` tags as following:-

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.11/angular.min.js"> 
</script>
<div ng-app>
    <p>{{accountID}}</p>
    <input class="form-control input-sm" uib-tooltip="Search by Account ID" validator="/^[0-9]{1,15}$/" validator-invoke="watch" validator-error="Account ID must have 1 to 15 digits." type="number" placeholder="Search by Account ID" ng-model="accountID" min="1" required>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not working as you haven't initialize Angular anywhere.Please check my example. i have made a  and make this div the owner of angular and now it's working fine

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.11/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="">
<p>{{accountID}}</p>

<input class="form-control input-sm" uib-tooltip="Search by Account ID" validator="/^[0-9]{1,15}$/" validator-invoke="watch" validator-error="Account ID must have 1 to 15 digits." type="number" placeholder="Search by Account ID"
  ng-model="accountID" min="1" required>
  </div>
```